# Heroku NodeJS index.js file is sent as a response instead of being executed

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, heroku

I have a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/timofeysie/tyno-lrs) that works for me locally for example by using 'npm start' or the CLI 'heroku local web', but only serves up the contents of the dist/index.js file when pushed to Heroku.

The app is in TypeScript and built with Gulp.

When the app is running locally, going to http://localhost:5000/api/v1/wiki/magical_thinking results in the correct description being returned.  However, after deploying the app, which has

`"start": "node dist/index.js", "postinstall": "gulp scripts"`

in the package.json file, and using the https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs buildpack, going to the url https://tyno-lrs.herokuapp.com/api/v1/wiki/magical_thinking will print out the index.js file instead of executing it.  I can't find any other issues that cover this behaviour so any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I belive that the problem is with static.json file. Your static.json looks like this:

```
{
"root": "dist/",
"clean_urls": true,
"routes": {
    "/**": "index.js"
 }
}
```

What means:

- `root`: This allows you to specify a different asset root for the directory of your application. For instance, if you're using ember-cli, it naturally builds a dist/ directory, so you might want to use that intsead.
- `clean_url`: For SEO purposes, you can drop the .html extension from URLs for say a blog site. This means users could go to /foo instead of /foo.html.
- `routes`: You can define custom routes that combine to a single file. This allows you to preserve routing for a single page web application.
  The following operators are supported:

  - supports a single path segment in the URL. In the configuration below, /baz.html would match but /bar/baz.html would not.
  - supports any length in the URL. In the configuration below, both /route/foo would work and /route/foo/bar/baz.

Described example of `routes`:

```
{
  "routes": {
    "/*.html": "index.html",
    "/route/**": "bar/baz.html"
  }
}
```

So it means that You host index.js file as an asset - that's why its content is displayed when You enter any site of You deployed application.

Comment: Hi METUAN, I have tried deleting the static.json, both in the repo and on the server.  But if I restart the server, the file gets re-instated and I still get the index.js file served up.  You provide some good information on what is causing this issue but how to resolve it?